# Конкатенация в setText() не нравится

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В качестве упражнения делаю простое приложение по заказу пиццы - выбор размера (влияет на цену) плюс дополнительный топпинг (тоже влияет на цену).

В итоге подбивается сумма заказа:

```
total.setText(getString(R.string.total_price_output) + String.format("%.02f", calculateTotal()));
```

Здесь total_price_output - это фраза "Total Price: $" в strings.xml, a метод calculateTotal() как раз и вычисляет общую стоимость заказа с учетом размеров и топпингов.

Все работает, но Андроид Студио выделяет эту строчку желтой черточкой, т.е. код не соответствует правилам хорошего тона и дает мне такую рекомендацию:

> Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders.

Как поступить? Добавить переменную, присвоить ей все, что сейчас идет в setText() и затем вызвать setText() с этой переменной?

Comment: [`Formatting strings`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Студия говорит о том, что правильнее использовать плейсхолдеры в ресурсах.

Пример из [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) (заголовок Formating strings).

строка в файле ресурсов:

```
 <string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

вызов в коде:

```
String text = getString(R.string.welcome_messages, username, mailCount);
```

на место `%1$s` в строке ресурсов подставится значение `username`, на место `%2$d` - `mailCount`. при этом `s` в плейсхолдере значит строку, а `d` - число.

в результате получим строку вида:*Hello, Petrov! You have 3 new messages*

Comment: Спасибо, тогда это очень помогло. Однако вчера потребовалось добавить третий параметр в строку - и возникла проблема с setText(): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/844730/android-java-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5