# как установить текст по умолчанию и дополнительный текст в textview?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

необходимо добавить дополнительный текст в textview. это значит что на пример в программе три кнопки которые будут отвечать за выбор цвета, так вот до нажатия кнопки в textview должен быть текст "Выбранный цвет - " а уже при нажатии на кнопку нужно добавлять к этой надписи выбранный цвет что бы на выходе получилось "Выбранный цвет - красный". Сейчас я пробовал задать текст "Выбранный цвет - " в xml но при нажатии на кнопку он пропадает и остается только название выбранного цвета. Возможно я не сильно понятно объяснил вопрос, если что спрашивайте.
String.xml

```
<string name="color">Выбранный цвет - %1$s.</string>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 radGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int id) {
                TextView selection = findViewById(R.id.selection);
                byte k;
                String color = null;
                switch(id) {
                    case R.id.red:
                        color = "КРАСНЫЙ";
                        //selection.setText("КРАСНЫЙ");
                        k = 'R';
                        myThreadConnected.write2(k);
                        break;
                    case R.id.green:
                        color = "ЗЕЛЕНЫЙ";
                        //selection.setText("ЗЕЛЕНЫЙ");
                        k = 'G';
                        myThreadConnected.write2(k);
                        break;
                    case R.id.blue:
                        color = "СИНИЙ";
                        //selection.setText("СИНИЙ");
                        k = 'B';
                        myThreadConnected.write2(k);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                String text = getString(R.string.color, color);
                selection.setText(text);
            }});
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/791089/177345

Comment: вполне рабочий вариант, но мне не сильно понятны некоторые детали. я сейчас могу вывести сообщение при использовании вашего варианта, но сообщение выводится все, а не так что до нажатия висит одно и потом еще к нему дописывается, мне не сильно понятно как использовать этот ресурс string в коде, то есть мы должны оставить setText с этим сообщением или же нужно юзать что то определенное для строковых ресурсов такого типа??

Comment: в начале вместо текста добавляйте пустую строку -
 "", а потом дописывайте что вам надо в переменную. Это просто текстовая строка типа String, использовать ее можно так же, как и другие строки, ничего отдельно определенного не требуется

Comment: я изменю вопрос немного а то не может не правильно понял

Comment: ну всё верно, начальное значение текста в виджет установите только еще **до слушателя**, потому что то, что у вас в слушателе будет выполнятся только при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: Но даже если установить значение текста до слушателя, а это я насколько понял просто переместить строку String text = getString(R.string.color, color); до слушателя, то текст все равно выводится уже после нажатия на radiobutton, вероятнее всего я в это раз точно не туда эту строку вставил, либо не правильно сформулировал вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView selection = findViewById(R.id.selection);
    selection.setText(getString(R.string.color, ""));

    radGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int id) {
            byte k;
            String color = null;
            switch(id) {
                case R.id.red:
                    color = "КРАСНЫЙ";
                    k = 'R';                       
                    break;
                case R.id.green:
                    color = "ЗЕЛЕНЫЙ";
                    k = 'G';
                    break;
                case R.id.blue:
                    color = "СИНИЙ";
                    k = 'B';
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            myThreadConnected.write2(k);
            selection.setText(getString(R.string.color, color));
        }});

}
```