# Android/Java — как выводить несколько переменных в строке?

Tags: java, android

Делаю простое приложение по заказу кофе, основываясь на одном курсе из [Udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud836), только добавляя свои фишки, ибо они оставляют много "дыр".

В общем, пользователь там накликивал нужное количество чашек кофе, добавлял сливки и/или шоколад по желанию, и жал кнопку "заказать".

В зависимости от того, что он там накликивал, в файле strings.xml хранились строки типа:

```
<string name="total_coffee_cost">Hi, %1$s. You ordered %2$d cups of coffee. \nPrepare to pay $%3$d. \nThank you!</string>
<string name="total_coffee_cost_whipped_cream">Hi, %1$s. You ordered %2$d cups of coffee, whipped cream will be added. \nPrepare to pay $%3$d. \nThank you!</string>
<string name="total_coffee_cost_chocolate">Hi, %1$s. You ordered %2$d cups of coffee, chocolate will be added. \nPrepare to pay $%3$d. \nThank you!</string>
<string name="total_coffee_cost_cream_chocolate">Hi, %1$s. You ordered %2$d cups of coffee, whipped cream and chocolate will be added. \nPrepare to pay $%3$d. \nThank you!</string>
<string name="total_coffee_cost_one">Hi, %1$s. You ordered %2$d cup of coffee. \nPrepare to pay $%3$d. \nThank you!</string>
<string name="total_coffee_cost_one_whipped_cream">Hi, %1$s. You ordered %2$d cup of coffee, whipped cream will be added. \nPrepare to pay $%3$d. \nThank you!</string>
<string name="total_coffee_cost_one_chocolate">Hi, %1$s. You ordered %2$d cup of coffee, chocolate will be added. \nPrepare to pay $%3$d. \nThank you!</string>
<string name="total_coffee_cost_one_cream_chocolate">Hi, %1$s. You ordered %2$d cup of coffee, whipped cream and chocolate will be added. \nPrepare to pay $%3$d. \nThank you!</string>
<string name="total_coffee_cost_zero">Hi, %1$s. You have not ordered any cup of coffee. \nTry to choose again. \nThank you!</string>
```

Выводилось в MainActivity.java все это через setText(), в зависимости от количества выбранного кофе с топпингами (там девять веток if-else, привожу две, чтобы не засорять):

```
private TextView createOrderSummary(View view){
    EditText nameField = findViewById(R.id.name_field);
    String name = nameField.getText().toString();

    CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
    hasWhippedCream = whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();

    CheckBox chocolateCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.chocolate_checkbox);
    hasChocolate = chocolateCheckBox.isChecked();

    TextView priceMessage = findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
    if (numberOfCoffees == 0)
        priceMessage.setText(getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_zero, name));
    else if ((numberOfCoffees == 1) && (!hasWhippedCream) && (!hasChocolate))
        priceMessage.setText(getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_one,name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup));
    else if ((numberOfCoffees == 1) && (hasWhippedCream) && (!hasChocolate))
        priceMessage.setText(getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_one_whipped_cream, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup));
    else if ((numberOfCoffees == 1) && (!hasWhippedCream) && (hasChocolate))
        priceMessage.setText(getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_one_chocolate, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup));
    else if ((numberOfCoffees == 1) && (hasWhippedCream) && (hasChocolate))
        priceMessage.setText(getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_one_cream_chocolate, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup));
    else if ((numberOfCoffees > 1) && (!hasWhippedCream) && (!hasChocolate))
            priceMessage.setText(getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup));
    else if ((numberOfCoffees > 1) && (hasWhippedCream) && (!hasChocolate))
            priceMessage.setText(getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_whipped_cream, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup));
    else if ((numberOfCoffees > 1) && (!hasWhippedCream) && (hasChocolate))
        priceMessage.setText(getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_chocolate, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup));
    else if ((numberOfCoffees > 1) && (hasWhippedCream) && (hasChocolate))
        priceMessage.setText(getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_cream_chocolate, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup));
    return priceMessage;
}
```

Все было хорошо, но потом в курсе решили добавить еще одну переменную - имя пользователя, которое тот вводит при заказе. И оказалось, что я не могу просто взять, и добавить третью переменную в строку, сделав, например, так:

```
<string name="total_coffee_cost">Hi, %1$s! You ordered %2$d cups of coffee. \nPrepare to pay $%3$d. \nThank you!</string>
```

Погуглив, выяснил, что метод setText() не может работать с тремя и более параметрами...

Как быть? В курсе Udacity не заморачиваются с этим - они напрямую выводят данные, не храня строки ни в strings.xml, не используя setText().

Должно же быть нормальное решение, ведь этих параметров может быть не три, как у меня, а намного больше...

Добавлю текст ошибки:
[image: Wrong argument count, format string total_coffee_cost_one requires 2 but format call supplies 3. This lint check ensures the following: (1) If there are multiple translations of the format string, then all translations use the same type for the same numbered arguments (2) The usage of the format string in Java is consistent with the format string, meaning that the parameter types passed to String.format matches those in the format string.]

> Wrong argument count, format string total_coffee_cost_one requires 2 but format call supplies 3. 
>   This lint check ensures the following:
>
> (1) If there are multiple translations of the format string, then all
>   translations use the same type for the same numbered arguments
>
> (2) The usage of the format string in Java is consistent with the
>   format string, meaning that the parameter types passed to
>   String.format matches those in the format string.

Проблема решена. Подсказали ввести промежуточную текстовую переменную, которую вставлять в setText(). Как только я ее добавил, Андроид Студио указала на синтаксические ошибки - отсутствие фигурных скобочек у каждого условия в if-else ветвлении.

Когда метод выглядит так, все отлично работает:

```
private TextView createOrderSummary(View view){
    EditText nameField = findViewById(R.id.name_field);
    String name = nameField.getText().toString();

    CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
    hasWhippedCream = whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();

    CheckBox chocolateCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.chocolate_checkbox);
    hasChocolate = chocolateCheckBox.isChecked();

    TextView priceMessage = findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);

    if (numberOfCoffees == 0) {
        textString = getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_zero, name);
        priceMessage.setText(textString);
    }
    else if ((numberOfCoffees == 1) && (!hasWhippedCream) && (!hasChocolate)) {
        textString = getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_one, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup);
        priceMessage.setText(textString);
    }
    else if ((numberOfCoffees == 1) && (hasWhippedCream) && (!hasChocolate)) {
        textString = getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_one_whipped_cream, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup);
        priceMessage.setText(textString);
    }
    else if ((numberOfCoffees == 1) && (!hasWhippedCream) && (hasChocolate)) {
        textString = getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_one_chocolate, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup);
        priceMessage.setText(textString);
    }
    else if ((numberOfCoffees == 1) && (hasWhippedCream) && (hasChocolate)) {
        textString = getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_one_cream_chocolate, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup);
        priceMessage.setText(textString);
    }
    else if ((numberOfCoffees > 1) && (!hasWhippedCream) && (!hasChocolate)) {
        textString = getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup);
        priceMessage.setText(textString);
    }
    else if ((numberOfCoffees > 1) && (hasWhippedCream) && (!hasChocolate)) {
        textString = getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_whipped_cream, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup);
        priceMessage.setText(textString);
    }
    else if ((numberOfCoffees > 1) && (!hasWhippedCream) && (hasChocolate)) {
        textString = getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_chocolate, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup);
        priceMessage.setText(textString);
    }
    else if ((numberOfCoffees > 1) && (hasWhippedCream) && (hasChocolate)) {
        textString = getString(R.string.total_coffee_cost_cream_chocolate, name, numberOfCoffees, numberOfCoffees * priceOfCup);
        priceMessage.setText(textString);
    }

    return priceMessage;
}
```

Comment: Вы тут что-то явно напутали, поскольку аргументы вам вставлять нужно в метод getString, но не в setText

Comment: Ради интереса. Посмотрите книгу "Паттерны проектирования" Фрименов (например тут https://vk.com/doc25651989_437513397?hash=8cebc0bcb1835219e7&dl=f0168e88a9ca6abb24 или погуглите) . Там в третьей главе прямо описано, как лучшим образом делать именно такие приложения. Хотя это и имеет мало отношения к вопросу, вам может быть полезно :)

Comment: судя по коду, вы вызываете строку с тремя параметрами, а передаете в нее лишь два.

Comment: В setText() у вас один параметр, а не два и тем более не три. В getString() количество параметров может и ограничено, но точно больше трех. Какая ошибка выводится? А для того, чтобы проще было читать код, лучше сначала собирать текст, а потом вставлять его в setText(), а не делать двести разных задач в одной строчке.

Comment: Возможно я примитивную вещь скажу, но почему нельзя вытянуть две отдельные строки из string.xml, а затем их просто сложить, и вставить в setText

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев, это неудобно. Особенно, когда строк много.

Comment: @Jarvis_J, когда я добавляю в строку третий параметр, я начинаю вызывать его и в getString(), появляется ошибка.

Comment: судя по ошибке он думает, что у вас два аргумента, а третий таковым не считает. Попробуйте просто переписать ваш <string>, может он какой-то символ не распознал или может у вас не "3" а "З" или % не кашерный. У меня все работает

Comment: В обсуждаемой строчке открывающих скобок больше, чем закрывающих.

Comment: Да и посмотрите заодно, действительно ли строка ``total_coffee_cost_one`` требует три аргумента, потому что в вопросе у вас ``total_coffee_cost``.

Comment: @Эникейщик по поводу скобок на скриншоте - это описка была, лишнюю удалил - та же ошибка высвечивается. Что касается количества аргументов - в строках задаю по 3 штуки, за исключением случая, когда "нулевой" заказ - я обновил все-таки исходный пост.

Comment: Я скопипастил ваш код, у меня все работает.

Comment: @Эникейщик, хм. Что же тогда делать? Сделать новый проект и в него скопипастить код со старого? Слышал, что такое бывает у Андроид Студио...